# Kendo grid not detecting keydown or keypress event

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, keypress, keydown

I have something like this

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer"> 
   <div class="myKendoGrid"> </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
     var grid = $(".myKendoGrid").data("kendoGrid");
     grid.table.on("keypress", function (e) {
          console.log('pressed');
     });
 });
```

**Problem:** Can't detect keypress or keydown in the grid.

Referenced from:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-row-delete-by-using-keyboard-delete-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't register a keypress or keydown event until you initiate a click event. Try the following.

```
$(".myKendoGrid").on("click", "table", function (e) {
        window.onkeydown = function (event) {
                alert("key pressed");
            }
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make sure this event fires ONLY when keypress happens within the 'div'? Right now it happens all over the document once I click it.

Comment: Try this : $(".test").on("click", "table", function (e) {
        $(this).find("div").on("keypress",function (event) {
                alert("key");
            });
    });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94872/discussion-between-rohan-and-dinomyte).

Answer (score 0):

Try with ID for DIV:

```
               $("#KGrid").on("click", ".myKendoGrid", function () {
...

}
```

```html
<div id="KGrid" class="myKendoGrid"> </div>
```